# Spring Data MongoRepository between for int values

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

having a class such as (this is `kotlin`, but the code is very understandable):

```
@Repository
interface ScoresRepository : MongoRepository<Score, String> {
    fun countAllByScoreIsBetween(min: Int, max: Int): Int
}

@Document
data class Score(
    @Id var score: Int,
)
```

Is the between inclusive or exclusive? That is, if I have scores 1-10, and I called:
`countAllByScoreIsBetween(3,6)` would I get 4 or 2? or maybe something else - bottom is inclusive and top is exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests (with `testcontainers`) show this:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var scoresRepository: ScoresRepository

@Test
fun test() {
    for (i in 1..10) {
        scoresRepository.save(Score(score = i))
    }

    val count = scoresRepository.countAllByScoreIsBetween(3, 6)

    assertThat(count).isEqualTo(2)
}
```

So as far as I see, both params are not included. That is, `Between` means everything between the values, not including the values themselves.